# Macro to export separate elements to separate png images in CorelDraw 17

Tags: corel-draw

Is there any macro to automate the export of multiple objects from CorelDraw 17 to separate png files as shown in the attached pic?

I have exported different objects as separate pngs hundreds of times before, but in the past I did it manually, so I want to find a faster way.

I found a macro [QuickExport](https://github.com/cdrpro-macros/quick-export) but it doesn't run as should.

**UPDATE:** QuickExport does run, i must to click its icon right-hand mouse button, it saves an image with presets. But unfortunately it doesn't save to separated files. So i still looking for a macro

[image]

Comment: How about the macro in this post?: https://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_graphics_suite_2017/f/coreldraw-2017/56764/multiple-images-export

Comment: @Joonas yea, thanks, my friend wrote the macro in such way, but added one more needed nesting feature

Answer (score 1):

I've found no such macros.
So my friend (his email: ***me@elvin.nsk.ru***) has agreed and coded such macros for me. More over, it not just exports the separate files but also embeds, nests one layer objects into another, you may see the preview how it works.

One slack because it isn't commercial there is no user interface so you need open VBA editor to change needed nesting and export settings.

[Here is the download link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8FFE/v1Y5AKyjb) or the [second link](https://github.com/LeksorHayabusa/elvin_PowerExport)

[image: macro nests one layer into another and finally export it as separate files]

How install the macro
Copy that GMS file into the User GMS folder;

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Corel\YOUR CORELDRAW VERSION\GMS`

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwOeQj6Y4OQ) how add to the toolbar an icon of the macro's command

Comment: Thank you very much, is what I was looking for, but unfortunately I do not understand the green letters of the VBA, and the corel close it i installed it as you describe here
I installed it as the github is an error in line 91 Set pclip_layer.Layer = ActivePage.Layers.Find(pclip_layer_name) i tried to follow your gif but it doesn't help too much, i renamed the layers with the text in the vba [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0II.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0II.jpg)

Comment: @sergio the green letters are comments in russian, but what you need to change is the name of ***pclip_layer_name*** and ***sh_layer_name***. ***pclip_layer_name*** - that's layer you want to pick, ***sh_layer_name*** - that's layer you want to put into it

Comment: @sergio hey, was it helpful?